# Edit Local Group Policy with Powershell

Tags: powershell, hardening

I have been looking into auditing my group policy using Powershell. However, being a small group not using Active Directory the answers I have found do not work because they employ RSAT which requires a domain to be configured. These issues are preventing me from automating these tasks because we aren't able to set up and configure a domain. Is there any way to edit our local security policy with Powershell?

I already know this has asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785463/enable-disable-local-group-policies-with-powershell) however, in my opinion, it wasn't answered correctly as it showed how to edit software policy in the registry which to my knowledge is not the same as the group policy. This has been more or less confirmed to my knowledge in my searching around the registry to find group policy in it.

Anyways I appreciate everyone's help and hope to sort this out, especially as similar questions relating to system security are largely outdated and have tended to not work anymore. Hopefully, if this is answered it'll help others in the community with similar problems.

Comment: What about this https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/cSecurityOptions/3.1.3

Comment: I will have to explore that one because the documentation seems a bit light however the description of the module sounds like it is what is needed.